# IBM Bluemix account with Outlook.com Email Address

Tags: outlook, ibm-cloud

IBM or their billing company won't allow any bluemix.com accounts with an `@outlook.com` email address. My question, does anyone else have this problem? Does anyone have a bluemix.com IBM cloud account with an outlook.com email address?

```
Hello,

As we do not support the Outlook Domain, would you mind creating another email to use?

Thank you


XXX XXXXXXXX
Representative, Revenue Services
IBM Cloud infrastructure
```

Answer (score 2):

I verified with management that the information in the email is correct. You cannot create an IBM Cloud platform account using an `@outlook.com` address due to historical issues with that domain. As recommended, please use an email address with a different domain.